# Docker multi platform builds extremely slow for ARM64 on Gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, arm64

I have the following dockerfile for a Node.js application

```
# ---> Build stage
FROM node:18-bullseye as node-build

ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn install --silent --production=true --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn build --silent

# ---> Serve stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=node-build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Up until now I was building exclusively for AMD64, but now I need to build also for ARM64.

I edited my .gitlab-ci.yml to look like the following

```
image: docker:20

variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: "project"
    BRANCH_NAME: "main"
    IMAGE_NAME: "$PROJECT_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TAG"

services:
    - docker:20-dind

build_image:
    script:
      # Push to Gitlab registry
      - docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
      - docker context create builder-context
      - docker buildx create --name builderx --driver docker-container --use builder-context
      - docker buildx build --tag $CI_REGISTRY/mygroup/$PROJECT_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME --push --platform=linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64 .
```

Everything works relatively fine for AMD64 but it is extremely slow for ARM64. Almost 10x slower than AMD64, giving me timeouts on the Gitlab Job.

Is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your pipeline is executing on amd64 hardware and that `docker buildx` is performing emulation to build the arm64 target. You will likely see a large improvement if you break `build_image` into two jobs (one for amd64 and one for arm64) and then send them to two different gitlab runners so that they each can execute on their native hardware.

Even if you can't or don't want stop using emulation, you could still break the `build_image` job into two jobs (one per image built) in hopes that running them in parallel will allow the jobs to finish before the timeout limit.

With changes to your Dockerfile and the use of image caching you can make some of your subsequent builds faster, but these changes won't help you until you get an initial image built (which can be used as the cache).

Updated `Dockerfile`:

```
# ---> Build stage
FROM node:18-bullseye as node-build

ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# only COPY yarn.lock so not to break cache if dependencies have not changed
COPY . /usr/src/app/yarn.lock 
RUN yarn install --silent --production=true --frozen-lockfile
# once the dependencies are installed, then copy in the frequently changing source code files
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn build --silent

# ---> Serve stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=node-build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Updated `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: docker:20

variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: "project"
    BRANCH_NAME: "main"
    IMAGE_NAME: "$PROJECT_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    REGISTRY_IMAGE_NAME: "$CI_REGISTRY/mygroup/$PROJECT_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME"
    CACHE_IMAGE_NAME: "$CI_REGISTRY/mygroup/$PROJECT_NAME/$PROJECT_NAME:cache"
    BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE: "1"

services:
    - docker:20-dind

stages:
   - build
   - push

before_script:
   - docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
   - docker context create builder-context
   - docker buildx create --name builderx --driver docker-container --use builder-context

build_amd64:
    stage: build
    script:
      - docker buildx build --cache-from "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME" --tag "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME"  --push --platform=linux/amd64 .

build_arm64:
    stage: build
    script:
      - docker buildx build --cache-from "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME" --tag "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME"  --push --platform=linux/arm64/v8 .

push:
   stage: push
   script: 
     - docker buildx build --cache-from "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME" --tag "$REGISTRY_IMAGE_NAME"  --push --platform=linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64 .
```

The `build_amd64` and `build_arm64` jobs each pull in the last image (of their arch) that was built and use it as a cache for docker image layers. These two build jobs then push their result back as the new cache.

The `push` stage runs `docker buildx ...` again, but they won't actually build anything new as they will just pull in the cached results from the two build jobs. This allows you to break up the builds but still have a single push command that results in the two different images ending up in a single multi-platform docker manifest.

Comment: After posting the question I continued to investigate and I ended up with the same conclusion, that I need ARM64 hardware to speed up the process. I'm currently using Gitlab shared runners, so I'm unsure what hardware is running on but most probably it's AMD64, so I'll have to configure my own runners. Regardless, this was a very well written and throughout answer! So thanks a lot!! I'll test this changes as soon as I manage to get a couple own runners in both AMD and ARM machines, but for me this is the answer so I'm going to mark as it :)

Comment: Question in the build stage, isn't `--cache-to` instead of `--cache-from`? Like this: `docker buildx build --cache-to "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME" --tag "$CACHE_IMAGE_NAME"  --push --platform=linux/amd64 .`

Comment: Also, the push stage is giving me trouble again, apparently it gets everything from the cache except the yarn install line in the dockerfile, same error as before. Do you know what could it be?

Comment: You could use`--cache-to`  instead of setting `BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE: "1"` as they are both used to determine how layers go into the cache. But you sill need `--cache-from` to utilize the cache data during the build.

Comment: I'm not sure what error you are referring to with "same error as before," as I don't see any error messages within the original question or the comments.

Comment: Sorry I've been adding some comments and deleting while I was fighting with this. It's weird because sometimes it worked but then stopped working. In the end the configuration that worked for me is this https://gist.github.com/jruiz94/f4b7bbb67e0ff7c71e9c582c7673af0c

Answer (score 0):

I ran the issue of slow builds on Google Cloud Build and ended up using native `arm64` hardware to speed up the `arm64` part of the build.

I wrote up a [detailed tutorial](https://medium.com/@DougDonohoe/faster-multi-architecture-docker-builds-on-google-cloud-build-using-arm64-vms-and-buildx-63c7b5ac017b) on this, which uses Docker contexts to point to the remote `arm64` VM.